# Pig - how to include ')' inside matches

Tags: apache-pig

```
X = FILTER DATA BY (text matches '.*are you there?).*');
```

It complains of `')'` being inside the matches argument. I tried using a *backslash* before it, but it still did not work. Any idea on how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
X = FILTER DATA BY (text matches '.*are you there?\\).*');
```

You need to escape the `)` (used for grouping) with a `\` and escape this `\` with another `\`.

Alternatively you can use `[)]`.

Note, that the same applies to `?` which is a special character in regex (1 or zero occurences).